# updating database that accepts null values on date and time textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net

i updated my code i added  .Value = DBNull.Value in the lines

any suggestions regarding updating database that accepts null values on date and time textbox any recommendations/suggestions are highly appreciated

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = sqlconn.CreateCommand
            sqlconn.Open()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "UpdateEquipmentProfile"

            'declare the variables'
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11, "oeq-su-999").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Category", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "COM").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_SubCategory", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "SU").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "adminpmis01").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_User", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "Ivan").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Brand", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "DELL").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Model", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "optiplex").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Specs", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000, "dualcore").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_SerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "sgh5960").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_PropertyNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "j7h7h6g6f2").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_MacAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "j7h7:h6g6f2").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Static_IP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "192.168.1.5").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Vendor", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "ADWAYS").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_PurchaseDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyStatus", SqlDbType.Char, 2, "IN").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "Good").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Dept_Code", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "ADM").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Location_Code", SqlDbType.Char, 8, "ADM_OFC").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Remarks", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000, "ACTIVE").Value = DBNull.Value
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_ID").Value = txtOEID.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_Category").Value = cmbCategory.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_SubCategory").Value = cmbSubCategory.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_Name").Value = txtName.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_User").Value = txtUser.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_Brand").Value = cmbBrand.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_Model").Value = cmbModel.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_Specs").Value = txtSpecs.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_SerialNo").Value = txtSerialNo.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_PropertyNo").Value = txtPropertyNo.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_MacAddress").Value = txtMacAddress.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_Static_IP").Value = txtStaticIp.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_Vendor").Value = txtVendor.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = txtPurchaseDate.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear").Value = txtWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_WarrantyStatus").Value = txtWarrantyStatus.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_Status").Value = txtStatus.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_Dept_Code").Value = cmbDeptCode.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_Location_Code").Value = cmbLocationCode.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@OE_Remarks").Value = txtRemarks.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Successfully Updated Equipment Profile")
            sqlconn.Close()
```

Comment: set @OE_PurchaseDate=NULL into SP. and don't pass the parameter so by default it's take NULL value

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi will this what i need to happen '@OE_PurchaseDate varchar(35)' changed to  '@OE_PurchaseDate=NULL'  in my stored proc?

Comment: @OE_PurchaseDate smalldatetime = NULL

Answer (score 0):

1.First of all if you have not set that DateTime field's allow null property,set it to allow null,so that it accepts null.

2.Then in your UI code dont pass the parameter if Date is not entered in Textbox.

3.Then in your code for passing parameter value check if the parameter value is null the pass that parameter's value as as DBNull.Value.